# How to prove the class of regular languages is closed under 3MAJ?

Tags: regular-languages

Let $\Sigma$ be some alphabet. We define the following operation on the set of all languages over $\Sigma$.

The operation $\mathrm{3MAJ}(L_1, L_2, L_3)$ takes in three languages $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ and outputs the language of all words that are members of the majority of the input
languages. Formally:
$$\mathrm{3MAJ}(L_1, L_2, L_3) = \{w \in \Sigma^*\mid\text{ at least two out of the }L_1, L_2, L_3\text{ contain }w\},$$
where $\Sigma^*$ is the set of all words over $\Sigma$. How to prove that the class of regular languages is
closed under the operation 3MAJ?

Comment: You should change the title of your post to be more explicit and linked to your question.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: We require you to credit the source of all copied material.  This appears to be copy-pasted word-for-word from some external source, without attribution (e.g., https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/question-3-regular-languages-closed-operations-let-alphabet-define-following-operation-set-q68697605).  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: This is a straightforward application of the product construction. You don't need our help if you understand the product construction.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** prove that $3MAJ(L_1, L_2, L_3) = (L_1 \cup L_2\cap L_3)  \ \cap \ (L_2 \cup L_1\cap L_3) \cap \ (L_3 \cup L_1\cap L_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider 3 regular languages $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$. By Kleene's theorem, there exist 3 DFA $\mathcal{A}_1 = (Q_1, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$, $\mathcal{A}_2 = (Q_2, \delta_2, q_2, F_2)$ and $\mathcal{A}_3 = (Q_3, \delta_3, q_3, F_3)$ that recognize respectively $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$. Let $\mathcal{A} = (Q, \delta, q_0, F)$ an automaton defined by:

- $Q = Q_1\times Q_2\times Q_3$;
- $q_0 = (q_1, q_2, q_3)$;
- $\forall (q, q', q'') \in Q, \forall a \in \Sigma, \delta((q, q', q''), a) = (\delta_1(q, a), \delta_2(q', a), \delta_3(q'', a))$ which means you read a word in all three automata simultaneously;
- $F = Q_1\times F_2\times F_3 \cup F_1\times Q_2\times F_3 \cup F_1\times F_2 \times Q_3$

Then $L(\mathcal{A}) = 3MAJ(L_1, L_2, L_3)$ (I leave the formal proof to you). That proves that regular languages are closed under $3MAJ$ operation.